# Issue in rewinding to oldest available message for KafkaConsumer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-python

I have rewinded fetch offset for one Kafka consumer in group G1 to off1 by following code:

```
  consumer1.set_topic_partitions((topic, partition, off1))
```

In the above line, off1 is offset of oldest available message for the topic in corresponding partition.

Now I am instantiating a Kafka consumer in different group G2 like following:

```
 consumer2 = KafkaConsumer(bootstrap_servers=broker,
                                  auto_offset_reset='smallest',
                                  auto_commit_enable=True,
                                  auto_commit_interval_ms=3000,
                                  group_id='G2'
                                  )
```

Here I am reading the fetch offset as off1 which is same as that I reset for the consumer1 in group G1. I think that should not happen as for different groups offset should be different. If anyone clarifies, I will be really grateful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Are both consumer groups reading the same topic?

If so consumer1 is getting set to the earliest offset and likewise the consumer2 is getting set to the earliest for the topic also by the fact of the following setting:

```
auto_offset_reset='smallest'
```

This will start the consumer at the earliest offset for the topic. To start consumer2 reading from the latest point in the topic use:

```
auto_offset_reset='largest'
```